# Scrapy Spider: Restart spider when finishes

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to make my Scrapy spider to launch again if the closed reason is because of my internet connection (during night internet goes down for 5 minutes).  When internet goes down the spider closes after 5 tries.

I'm trying to use this function inside my spider definition trying to restart the spider when closed:

```
def handle_spider_closed(spider, reason):
    relaunch = False
    for key in spider.crawler.stats._stats.keys():
        if 'DNSLookupError' in key:
            relaunch = True
            break

    if relaunch:
        spider = mySpider()
        settings = get_project_settings()
        crawlerProcess = CrawlerProcess(settings)
        crawlerProcess.configure()
        crawlerProcess.crawl(spider)
        spider.crawler.queue.append_spider(another_spider)
```

I tried a lot of things like re instantiate an spider but got the error *Reactor is already running* or something like that.

I thought about executing the spider from a script, and when the spider finishes call it again, but didn't work neither, because of the reactor is still in use.

- My intention is to reset the spider after it closes (the spider closes because it lost internet connection)

Does anyone knows a good and easy way to do this ?

Comment: A scenario to investigate would be using scrapy jobs (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html) to deal with persistence between different spider instances and shell scripting to check for example every 10 minutes if the scrapy process is active. if not relaunch it

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: what if you would use `spider.crawler.crawl(spider)` after reinstantiating a spider? Thanks.

Comment: I've read that docs but I dont understand how to automatically restart the spider when it closes

Comment: @alecxe I've tríed that but it says cant run it because of reactor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue ! What was I trying to do ?

- Handle the spider when fails or closes
- Try to reexecute the Spider when closes

I managed by handling the error of the spider like this:

```
import time

class mySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    allowed_domains = ["google.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.google.com",
    ]

    def handle_error(self, failure):
        self.log("Error Handle: %s" % failure.request)
        self.log("Sleeping 60 seconds")
        time.sleep(60)
        url = 'http://www.google.com'
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, errback=self.handle_error, dont_filter=True)

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'http://www.google.com'
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, errback=self.handle_error)
```

- I used `dont_filter=True` to make the Spider allow to duplicate a request, only when it goes through error.
- `errback=self.handle_error` makes the Spider go through the custom `handle_error` function