# Scrapy, restart the script

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a working spider, but sometimes it throws an error. When it does,  I want it to restart the script from the beginning.

I have tested with a `while` loop, but the spider isn't relly designed for it. I'm able to catch the error with an `if` statement like this:

```
if response.status == error code:
  #here I want it do restart the script from the beginning
else:
  #continue scraping
```

I have tried `os.execv(__file__,sys.argv)` but I had no luck.

Comment: can this be of any help? https://blog.petrzemek.net/2014/03/23/restarting-a-python-script-within-itself/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy Spider: Restart spider when finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987240/scrapy-spider-restart-spider-when-finishes)

Comment: its not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987240/scrapy-spider-restart-spider-when-finishes @KaushikNP because i want to restart when the error occurs

Comment: All you would need to do is call the Error handler as mentioned in the accepted answer for that post. But, am having my doubts. Just tried it out as it proposes there, and the thing is, it only works once, as I suspected. The answer only works when you have one URL to work on and not for many, since it will be skipped as a duplicate request. Unless you allow all the requests to work with duplicate url, it won't work